# Query builder - display everything besides the users answer

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following problem to solve.

I want to display everything besides the own users answer. Let me give you an example.

Step 1: Users enters an answer to a question

Step 2: I save that answer to a database

Step 3: The user can now upvote OTHER people questions

Step 3*: Here i show every existing question but I don't want the current users answer to show.

Here is my query. (In AnswerRepository)

```
    $query = $queryBuilder
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->neq('a.user', ':user'))
        ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('a.diveIndex', ':diveIndex'))
        ->setParameter('diveIndex', $getDiveIndex)
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
```

Sadly the first where does not really work, since I can still see the current user questions when I list all answers.

Answer Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="answerBody", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $user;
```

User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Answer::class, mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $answerBody;
```

Controller Call :

```
 $answers = $this->answerRepository->findByIndexAndUser($dto->geIndex(), $this->user);
```

Comment: Is there a Question entity involved somewhere? You mention questions and answers, but code only shows answers. I have a feeling that you are filtering/hiding only the Answers from the own user, but not the Questions (if there exist such) - in which case you probably want to JOIN the questions table/relation and apply the user on that one instead.

Comment: Hey. No there is no question entity.

Comment: Could you please then extend your pasted code with full methods and entity classes relevant to this? From what's here nothing pops out as odd.
Also, you don't need the expr() for simple conditions, e.g. `$queryBuilder->expr()->neq('a.user', ':user')` is just as good as `'a.user <> :user'`
Also in your controller you seem to use `$this->user` rather than the usual `$this->getUser()` - are you sure the passed user is not actually `null`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT a FROM Answer a WHERE a.userId != :userId AND a.diveIndex = :diveIndex")
->setParameter('userId', $user->getId())
->setParameter('diveIndex', $getDiveIndex);

return $query->getResult();
```

if you have a `userId` property in your Answer class.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to use entity objects as parameters, there is no need to forcefully convert them to IDs. That becomes extra convenient when you have multi-column primary keys (entity identifiers)

Comment: Hi sadly I get `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'Answer a WHERE': Error: Class 'Answer' is not defined.`

Comment: Try full class name (FQCN)

Comment: @mkilmanas thanks, I never tried to use an object

Comment: @MichaelKrutikov I don't understand, what do you mean ? Can you maybe edit your answer ?

Comment: What MichaelKrutikov means is that you need to use a full class name including namespace, something like `App\Entity\Answer` (or it might be enough just to have this class imported (i.e. `use App\Entity\Answer;`  at the top of the file - but this is unverified guess)

Comment: In the select statmenet ?